# Can I use EF code-first with SQL Server CE on WPF?

Tags: wpf, ef-code-first

I would like to use a local SQL Server CE in my app; I've read that using EF code-first I can let the system create the db starting from POCO classes; I've configured `EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact` using NuGet but it's not clear to me how can I use it in my WPF app....can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter whether you use the default WPF style application development or MVVM pattern, as long as you have a separate data layer.

Your data layer should hide away all of the DB implementation logic, including the creation of the DB from the rest of your code.

You could implement it using the Repository pattern, but as long as it provides a known interface and definitions for the data objects that your business logic requires you should be okay.

Note that the data objects used by the other layers of code do not need to be the same as the POCO objects used by the DB.

If you have your data layer accessed by a Singleton class that implements the layer's interface then you could automatically call the DB creation code if the DB can not be found when `DataLayer.Instance` (for example) is called.

The important thing to remember is that only the internal workings of the datalayer should know where the data comes from the rest of your code should be DB agnostic, only caring that it has the data that it needs, not where it comes from.

As for practicalities [here's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx) a link that gives a Code First with EF example.